# class.ind in data.table in r

Tags: r, data.table

Take this toy `data.table`:

```
dt <- data.table(a=1:3,k=letters[2:4],e=4:6)

   a k e
1: 1 b 4
2: 2 c 5
3: 3 d 6
```

I want to convert variable "k" to dummy(k)

I can do like this,

```
dt[,class.ind(k)]
cbind(dt[,1,with=FALSE],dt[,class.ind(k)],dt[,3,with=FALSE])
```

resulting in:

```
   a b c d e
1: 1 1 0 0 4
2: 2 0 1 0 5
3: 3 0 0 1 6
```

I think that there must be an easier way.

Answer (score 2):

Use `dcast.data.table`. You need a variable or function that will return 1/0 indicating whether a combination is present.

```
 library(reshape2)
# using a variable)
k_ind <-  dcast.data.table(dt[,.N,by=names(dt)], a+e~k,fill=0L)
k_ind
#    a e b c d
# 1: 1 4 1 0 0
# 2: 2 5 0 1 0
# 3: 3 6 0 0 1

# using a function
k_ind2 <-  dcast.data.table(a+e ~ k, data=dt, fun=function(x) any(length(x))+0L)



# you can change the column order using setcolorder


setcolorder(k_ind, c('a',unique(dt[['k']]),'e'))
k_ind
#    a b c d e
# 1: 1 1 0 0 4
# 2: 2 0 1 0 5
# 3: 3 0 0 1 6
```

Comment: Was just about to post a `model.matrix` answer, but this is nicer.

Comment: i don't understand how to work "any(x)+0L" 
can you explain me.